# Why keyboard keys are not in alphabetical order?

Tags: keyboard

It seems to be silly question, but i really wonder 'Why keyboard keys are not placed in alphabetical order?' Is there any specific reason?

Comment: dude, that's not really server/sysadmin related is it? I'm not going to DV it because I'm a happy camper but you should consider looking on wikipedia or googling it - it's all we'd do.

Comment: google "QWERTY History"

Answer (score 17):

This is a good question with no simple answer.

Most people think the reason is that for touch typists the most often used characters are
typed with the fingers that are stronger.  This is not really true. You can easily check this 
yourself with a [Letter Frequency table](http://www.simonsingh.net/The_Black_Chamber/frequencyanalysis.html) and a [Touch Typing diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_typing).

The real reason is:

If you **hit two keys that are next to each other** on a mechanical typewriter simultaneously or in quick succession **they lock up** and the typewriter can even get damaged.

So the designers tried to spread out the keys which were close in often used words or phrases to minimize this effect. Mechanical typewriters are long gone, but the layout stayed because 
touch typists are used to it.

Comment: Of course the side effect of this is, keyboards are actually designed to slow down the speed you type at.

Comment: @Richard Slater: Exactly, and this is where alternative keyboard layouts come into play.

Comment: Hmm, I've heard this said hundreds of time, but I've also heard it said that it's a common myth...

Comment: Maybe, but it's not as easy to prove or disprove as the letter frequency myth...

Comment: I don't agree that spacing the keys out would actually make you slower. If anything, using keys that are further spaced apart allows you to type faster since you can use alternating fingers and can be already pressing the next key when the previous is on the rebound.

Comment: Exactly Kamil. While the "odd" ordering makes typing slower for beginner typists (because they can't find the right keys quickly until the layout is learned) for those that could type faster then the machinery could cope with (because of the print levers colliding/jamming) in the alphabetical arrangement it actually allowed them to go faster than they otherwise would.

Comment: I think the suggestion that it's a myth is a myth. :-)

Comment: I think we need to get MythBusters onto it!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a coincidence or not, but all the letters required to spell the word "typewriter" are on the top row.  Think "product demo".

Comment: Takes all three rowes for that one :-)

Answer (score 0):

Because on the originals typewriting machines the most frequently used letters were spaced away to avoid mechanics pieces to be tired quickly.

Answer (score 0):

It is fascinating how Wikipedia and Google are difficult to use sometimes:

google for: *reason for keyboard layout*

First one that pops up will be [QWERTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY) on Wikipedia, and there's a short story explaining the layout from several points of view.